# Speed up \includegraphics of large (vector) pdf figures

Tags: pdf, includegraphics

I would like to `\includegraphics{}` of monthly water avaialbility in ~8000 of the worlds watersheds (see graphic below) in my final pdf. I have the graphic as a pdf with a size of approximately 23 MB. The creation of a PDF in which I include the pdf-graphic of the watersheds takes forever (and that's already the case with only one of the graphics included in my document). Is there a way to speed up the process? I want to include up to 20 of these graphics in my final work.
I am using TeXstudio and XeLaTeX as a default compiler.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{log.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use the draft setting.

Comment: In principle, there is not size limitation, right? It may just take a night to create the PDF ... ?

Comment: Is the PDF a bitmap or a vector diagram?

Comment: Vector diagram ...

Comment: Well I saw once a failure because someone tried to create a gigabyte pdf and started the second compilation before the system was able to finish writing the pdf of the first to the disc. Beside this large pdf can be quite slow and unresponding, so I would really try to make the graphics smaller.

Comment: you are scaling the graphic every time? Is that scaling a big pdf down as if it is you are probably including vast amounts of data that makes no difference to the rendering at normal screen sizes. You could make a one-off rendering of the pdf to a reasonable A4 /letter sized png file and include that. Certainly for drafts but probably for the final document, unless you expect the reader to zoom in to specific regions at arbitrary detail. For an extreme example the image in your question is a 600Kb png file rather than 23Mb pdf, include that,

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. The idea is, that readers can zoom into the figures in the report. Therefore, raster images are not really an option (unless high-resolution ones which would probably be around the same size).

Comment: Are there any differences in the compiling speed of the different compilers? I am currently running a test with 20 of my figures ... it has been running for about an hour now and is still going :) I can live with basically any compiling time as long as it is reliable :)

Comment: With 20 of my figures it took about 4+1/2 hours and the final document is ~430MB in size ... not too bad :)